# Python lists search

Tags: python, list

A better way of searching the list? Any suggestions appreciated:

```
for key in nodelist.keys():
    if len(nodelist[key]) > 0:
        if key == "sample_node":
            print key + ":"
            print nodelist[key]
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Describe it in English. Be **precise**. Give examples of expected input and output, if you think it will help.

Comment: This isn't a "search".  It's a "filter".  Also, `nodeList` can't possibly be a list, it must be a dictionary for any of this to make sense.

Answer (score 4):

It is simpler to write this code:

```
key = "sample_node"
if key in nodelist:  # loop not needed, and .keys() not needed
    value = nodelist[key]
    if value:  # len() not needed
        print key + ":"
        print value
```

Comment: … and the reason for the downvote is…?

Comment: You might want to fix your code formatting.  (There's a never closed quote on the first line.)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand hey man, just edit it dont use downvote ;)

Comment: *If* this is what the question is asking, this solution works fine.

Comment: @Efazati, I wouldn't down vote for that.  I was just speculating  :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
key = "sample_node"
if key in nodelist:
    print ''.join([key, ":", nodelist[key]])
```

Comment: The `if len() > 0` part is missing…

Comment: I took that as his naive approach to "if this item in the dictionary is set."

Comment: The test in the question means "if the value has a non-zero length", instead. For instance, `nodelist = {"sample_node": []}` does not print anything, in the original question, but does print something in your answer.

Comment: Correct, and I don't think that's what he wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If the type of `nodelist` is `dict`:

```
>>> key = 'sample_node'
>>> if nodelist.get(key):
...     print key+':'+str(nodelist[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[k+':'+str(v) for k,v in nodelist.items() if k == 'sample_node' and v]
```

And if you just need to print the results:

```
for s in (k+':'+str(v) for k,v in nodelist.items() if k == 'sample_node' and v):
    print s
```

Comment: plus for one line for ;)

Comment: if you assume that `nodelist` is a dictionary (by using `.items()`) then you don't need the for-loop: [`k = 'sample_node'; v = nodelist.get(k); if v: print "%s:\n%s" % (k, v)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8628297/4279)

Answer (score 1):

```
filter( lambda x: nodeList[x], nodeList )
```